# Unable to locate current JTA transaction during integration of Jboss Resteasy and Spring

Tags: java, spring, resteasy, jta, lazy-initialization

Can any one help me with correct approach to integrate Resteasy and Spring with AOP declartive configuration for JTA transaction.

The configuration is as per below,

**Project structure:**

```
com.example.dao
   - UserDAO
com.example.daoimpl
   - UserDAOImpl
com.example.services.api
   - EmployeeApi
com.example.services.api.impl
   - EmployeeApiImpl
```

**aop.xml**

```
    <tx:advice id="txServiceAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <!-- all methods starting with search/view/get/is are read-only -->
            <tx:method name="search*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="view*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="is*" read-only="true"/>

            <!-- all other methods require transaction -->
            <tx:method name="*" read-only="false"
                propagation="REQUIRED"
                isolation="READ_COMMITTED"
                rollback-for="RuntimeException"
                no-rollback-for="ServiceException" />

        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>

       <aop:config>
          <aop:pointcut id="restApiPointcut" expression="execution(* com.example.services.*.*(..))"/>
          <aop:advisor advice-ref="txServiceAdvice" pointcut-ref="restApiPointcut"/>
       </aop:config>
```

I followed the ApplicationContextAware intrefaces approch mentioned here https://mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-spring-integration-example/

The EmployeeApiImpl look like below,

```
@Path("/requests")
@Component
public class EmployeeApiImpl {



   @GET
   @Path("/{id}")
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   @Transactional
   public int findUserCountByEmpId(@PathParam(value = "id") Long id) throws ServiceException {
      UserDAO userDAO= SpringApplicationContext.getBean("UserDAO", UserDAOImpl.class);
      return userDAO.findCountById(id);
   }

}
```

When I call the api then it's giving below error,

```
 14:59:27,477 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /example-fe-war/api/requests/170: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleApplicationException(ExceptionHandler.java:82)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:346)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:457)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate current JTA transaction
        at org.hibernate.context.internal.JTASessionContext.currentSession(JTASessionContext.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:464)
        atcom.example.dao.application.application.impl.AbstractBaseDAOImpl.getSession(AbstractBaseDAOImpl.java:116)
        atcom.example.dao.application.application.impl.GenericDAOImpl.findById(GenericDAOImpl.java:43)
        at com.example.services.api.impl.EmployeeApiImpl.findCountById(EmployeeApiImpl.java:29)
        at com.example.services.api.impl.EmployeeApiImpl$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.findCountById(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:338)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
        ... 60 more
```

---------------added service layer as per suggestion-------------------------

```
@Path("/requests")
public class EmployeeApiImpl   {

   @GET
   @Path("/{id}")
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public int findUserCountByEmpId(@PathParam(value = "id") Long id) throws ServiceException {
      ExampleService exampleService = SpringApplicationContext.getBean("exampleService", ExampleService.class);
      return exampleService.findUserCountByEmpId(id);
   }

}
```

```
public class ExampleService {


   @Transactional
   public int findUserCountByEmpId(Long id) throws ServiceException {
     UserDAO userDAO= SpringApplicationContext.getBean("UserDAO", UserDAOImpl.class);
      return userDAO.findCountById(id);
   }
}
```

```
13:17:02,254 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /example-fe-war/api/requests/170: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'Address' from com.example.entities.User
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler.handleException(ExceptionHandler.java:356)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:193)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:539)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:461)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY008205: JSON Binding serialization error javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'Address' from com.example.entities.User
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jsonb.JsonBindingProvider.writeTo(JsonBindingProvider.java:160)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:137)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ServerWriterInterceptorContext.writeTo(ServerWriterInterceptorContext.java:61)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:124)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.security.doseta.DigitalSigningInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(DigitalSigningInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:129)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.lambda$writeNomapResponse$2(ServerResponseWriter.java:151)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ContainerResponseContextImpl.filter(ContainerResponseContextImpl.java:399)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.executeFilters(ServerResponseWriter.java:219)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:95)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ServerResponseWriter.writeNomapResponse(ServerResponseWriter.java:69)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.writeResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:530)
        ... 61 more
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'User' from com.example.entities.Address
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.serializeRoot(Marshaller.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.marshall(Marshaller.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.Marshaller.marshall(Marshaller.java:102)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.JsonBinding.toJson(JsonBinding.java:118)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.jsonb.JsonBindingProvider.writeTo(JsonBindingProvider.java:156)
        ... 72 more
Caused by: javax.json.bind.JsonbException: Unable to serialize property 'additionalRequestTypeInfo' from com.example.entities.User_$$_jvst356_26b
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serialize(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.AbstractContainerSerializer.serializerCaptor(AbstractContainerSerializer.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:65)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:153)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:266)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
        at com.example.entities.User_$$_jvst356_26b.toString(User_$$_jvst356_26b.java)
        at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.GetValueCommand.getValue(GetValueCommand.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.ReflectionPropagation.getValue(ReflectionPropagation.java:73)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.model.PropertyModel.getValue(PropertyModel.java:284)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.marshallProperty(ObjectSerializer.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.yasson.internal.serializer.ObjectSerializer.serializeInternal(ObjectSerializer.java:65)
        ... 82 more
```

How can I integrate Resteasy and Spring with JTA correctly? I went throuh many official document and other post but it did not help so please help me if someone know how I can call userDAO.findCountById with proper transaction. The transaction aop configuration for spring classes is working but not for classes annotated with @ path and @ componant

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace**. If your `EmployeeApiImpl` is an `@Component` don't do a lookup but use dependency injection to inject the `UserDAO`.However the fact that you get the exception is likely an indication that your Resteasy / Spring integration doesn't work (and basically using the lookup hides that).

Comment: Thank you for comment. When I try to use setter based dependency injection using declartive approach then the userDAO is null but other spring class has valid reference to userDAO. Whenever class with @ Path and @ Component try to inject this DAO class then it's either null( dependency injection ) or Unable to locate current JTA(with lookup). I'll add full stacktrace

Comment: added full stacktrace

Comment: If there is no injection, the `@Component` is useless and thus an indication your Spring integration isn't steup properly (else you wouldn't need the workaround with the lookup). Also marking your endpoint `@Transactional` (basically your web layer) isn't the best either. Create a service that has an `@Transactional` method and call that from your endpoint (with or without a lookup). Looking at your current setup I would suggest just adding a service layer in between.

Comment: tried with service layer in between but the result is same as service is null when I inject  using declartive approach,
```
@Path("/requests")
public class EmployeeApiImpl   {

   ExampleService exampleService;

   public void setExampleService(ExampleService exampleService) {
      this.exampleService = exampleService;
   }
   @GET
   @Path("/{id}")
   @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
   public IbisRequest findUserCountByEmpId(@PathParam(value = "id") Long id) throws ServiceException {
      return exampleService.findUserCountByEmpId(id);
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't add code as comments that is totally unreadable. I stated use the approach you now have (the lookup) and introduce a service layer with `@Transactional`.

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have updated question with code. with this approach I think transaction part is working but not completely as getting error Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session.

I have added error log to question

Comment: Let me guess, you are using JPA and decided to add Lombok into the mix and use `@Data`. In your dao you are doing somet logging with the user(s) that are retrieved (or using `System.out`). Or this stacktrace isn't the one that comes with the code you shown herer (please add the full stacktrace and not a snippet).

Comment: added the full stacktrace

Comment: The stacktrace is modified with names as removed class name from actual code. we have spring application with entity classes and declartive hbm configuration and we now want to integrate jboss resteasy which are using bean from spring applications

Comment: That doesn't answer my question(s). Do you have entities with `@Data` or at least some reflective `toString` method (as it appears that way).  Also why resteasy instead of just plain Spring controllers (as you are already using Spring) which saves you a lot of headaches.

Comment: we don't have entities with @Data, we have entities which are implementing Serializable interface and override toString() and for plain Spring controllers, could you please give me any reference to some document? or example to implement rest api with  Spring controllers

Comment: If you look at your stacktrace the `toString` is the problem as you are probably logging something and the `toString` is printing (probably lazy loaded) collections.

Comment: yes, logging is there, is there any way so that it'll work with  lazy loaded? I tried with opensessioninviewfilter but did not work

Comment: finally it's working. The issue was aop configuration and use of ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper to transform the response to josn. Thank your for your help